# CPU USAGE IN SQL BOX

Tags: sql-server

Is there a best number that a CPU usage be for a SQL BOX. I just want to make it clear that what is the preferable number. Please, suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the best CPU utilization for a database server?  This question doesn't really have an answer.  In the best case, your CPU utilization would be at 100% with no processes waiting.

Looking purely at CPU usage won't tell you much. A database is CPU bound, but also memory and I/O bound.

What is the actual problem that you're looking to solve?

Comment: The procees was very slow so wanted to be sure.

Comment: If your queries are slow and the CPU isn't pegged, then you should start looking at memory and I/O.  Disk access costs a lot in terms of performance.  You might also look at what's going over the network if that applies in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best number. Anything less than 100% is preferable. :-)

It depends on the variability of you workload. You need extra capacity for spikes in workload.

If you have extremely consistent workload then 80%-90% avg CPU would be fine.  If it is highly variable then your avg CPU should be a lot lower.

If the CPU is pegged then processes will be waiting and get bogged down. That's a bad thing. So add as much CPU as you can afford to prevent the 100% CPU from occurring to often. How often is acceptable is up to you and your budget.